# How can i get Instagram json data on Android?

Tags: android, json

I want to use Instagram data in my Android app without using API. I am having trouble because I haven't worked with .json and volley library before. With the link below, we can get the data of Instagram user as json.

**Get Json Datas On Instagram:**
https://www.instagram.com/android/?__a=1

I want to take this data as json in the Android application and take the username as an example. I tried a lot of things but I didn't get an answer. It gives errors and does not return any results. The reason I got the error is that I need to break up the data in two sets so that I can pull the data I want to get. So I couldn't find an answer and didn't get the username. I would be glad if you help. I'm sorry for my bad english. If what I wrote is incomprehensible, please refer to the codes and screenshot. You will definitely understand.

> **My Activity;**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button Find_Button;
    private TextView Find_Textview;
    private String urlJsonArry = "https://www.instagram.com/android/?__a=1";
    String data = "";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private String jsonResponse;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        Find_Button = findViewById(R.id.button_login_01);
        Find_Textview = findViewById(R.id.textview_login_01);

Find_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                makeJsonArrayRequest();

            }
        });

    }

private void makeJsonArrayRequest() {

        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(urlJsonArry,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d("result", response.toString());

                        try {
                            // Parsing json array response
                            // loop through each json object
                            jsonResponse = "";
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject person = (JSONObject) response
                                        .get(i);

                                JSONObject phone = person
                                        .getJSONObject("graphql");
                                String name = phone.getString("username");

                                jsonResponse += "userName: " + name + "\n\n";

                            }

                            Find_Textview.setText(jsonResponse);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d("errorTAG", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
    }

}
```

**> AppController.class;**

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json given by Insta is starting from JSONobject not JSONArray. Please make the following corrections in your code.
**Updated**

```
private void makeJsonArrayRequest() {

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            urlJsonArry,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    // Do something with response
                    //mTextView.setText(response.toString());

                    // Process the JSON
                    jsonResponse = "";
                    try{
                        // Get the JSON array
                        JSONObject person =  response;

                        JSONObject graphqlObject = person
                                .getJSONObject("graphql");
                        JSONObject userObject = person
                                .getJSONObject("user");
                        String name = userObject.getString("username");

                        jsonResponse += "userName: " + name + "\n\n";


                        Find_Textview.setText(jsonResponse);

                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }
    );

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I also tried this, but in android studio it shows errors in the codes that I can not understand why. I wonder if it was withdrawn from the volley library?

screenshot: https://prnt.sc/rkcain

Comment: i added dear but not working. When i delete it, it works. "JSONObject person =  response;"

Comment: oh, ok. thank you. We had to add "null" when making a json request. But I noticed something in the code. "JSONObject graphqlObject = person
                                     .getJSONObject ("graphql"); "this place does not work at all. This object has never been used. In this way, json cannot get any data.

Comment: If we want to read the object nested, we should use this. I figured it all out. Thank you so much for your help. "JSONObject graphqlObject = person
                                    .getJSONObject("graphql").getJSONObject("user");"

Comment: @İsaC. I am happy that it helped you. Passing a null mean there is no request body for the JsonRequest .